# Помогите с программой на python библиотека tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как вычислить индекс массы тела. По сути я не понимаю как провести операцию с числом в взятым из поля ввода. Вот код.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def math():
    index_ves = int(ves.get())
    index_rost= int(ves.get())
    index = index_ves/index_rost
    messagebox.showerror("Ваш индекс", index)
head = Label(root, text="Программа для рассчёта индекса массы тела")
vesstr=Label(root, text="Введите ваш вес")
roststr=Label(root, text="Введите ваш рост")
ves = Entry()
rost = Entry()
btn = Button(root, text="Ответить", command=math)

head.grid()
vesstr.grid()
ves.grid()
roststr.grid()
rost.grid()
btn.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Есть ещё такой вариант тоже не работает

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def math():
    try:
        index_ves = int(ves.get())
        index_rost= int(rost.get())
        index.config(text="Сумма числе будет равна {}".format(index_ves / index_rost))
    except ValueError:
        index.config(text="Ошибка введите цифры")   

head = Label(root, text="Программа для рассчёта индекса массы тела")
vesstr=Label(root, text="Введите ваш вес")
roststr=Label(root, text="Введите ваш рост")
ves = Entry(root) #answer
rost = Entry(root)
btn = Button(root, text="Ответить", command=math)
label = Label(root, text="Вай индекс равен")

head.grid()
vesstr.grid()
ves.grid()
roststr.grid()
rost.grid()
btn.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы считываете введённые значения в функции расчёта:

```
def math():
    index_ves = int(ves.get())
    index_rost= int(ves.get())
```

вы оба раза читает поле *ves*. Исправьте так:

```
def math():
    index_ves = int(ves.get())
    index_rost= int(rost.get())
```

и всё работает :-)